# visibility: collapse within a scrollable container produces unwanted scrollbar in Firefox/Edge

Tags: html, css

It seems like wrapper's div height is incorrectly calculated when thead's visibility is set to collapsed in Firefox/Edge. In Chrome there is no scrollbars. Any idea how to fix it?

```css
.table-wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: green;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

thead {
  visibility: collapse
}
```

```html
<div class="table-wrapper">
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Head</th>        
    <th>Head</th>
    <th>Head</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>    
    <tr><td>Content</td></tr>        
    <tr><td>Content</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Content</td></tr>        
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: and why u r using `overflow : auto` it also causes this problem , if u dont need it , just remove it and ur problem will be solved . other ways set it to `hidden` , also u didnt tell us the purpose of doing this so we may come up with new ways to achieve it

Comment: @SUB-HDR Purpose is a topic for different question, but ok, here it is: to create a html table having: fixed header, scrollable body, cell's fit to content, using pure CSS, without hardcoding any height nor width. https://jsfiddle.net/1xc1kz8s/3/

Comment: the example in fiddle seems to work normal in firefox , and scrollbar apear only when there is small amount of content and @Mike.McCaughan answer solve it in this condition . if there is larg amount of content and u want to hide the scrollbar but keeping the scroll ability i can help u with that .

Comment: how can I determine that there is small amount of content (like here for instance https://jsfiddle.net/1xc1kz8s/13/) and use @Mike.McCaughan solution without using JavaScript?

Comment: @SUB-HDR _"if there is large amount of content and u want to hide the scrollbar but keeping the scroll ability i can help u with that"_ - Is it possible without JavaScript? How would you do it?

Comment: here is the way : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49088693/7465452

Comment: How end-user would know she can scroll the content?

Comment: And the end-user would have to click on the arrow/text I suppose? Wouldn't that require JavaScript code? Or am I wrong?

Comment: well u ask about hiding the scrollBar and thats come with price , ur going to use javascript in some point u cant run from that , it dosnt have to be long JavaScript codes u can solve many things with small lines since querySelectorAll is widely supported now ... otherways use @Mike-McCaughan answer it seems to solve your problem. ---
and by the way you can make that end up line : "scroll for more" . so they know its not clickable .

Comment: Well yes, you are right, the conversation went to a place, where I indeed did ask for it :) But what I meant, was to have Chrome's behavior in Firefox and Edge. **In Chrome there is no need for JavaScript** Sorry for not being clear. _"and by the way you can make that end up line : "scroll for more""_ - sounds interesting, I will do some testing.

Comment: At the moment I cannot accept your answer. Nor @Mike-McCaughan. Both are helpful and will work for certain use cases, but are not complete solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's likely because the scrollbar's existence is determined before the `thead` is removed from the flow in those browsers. When I scroll down, the amount of space after the table is about that of the hidden `thead`.

Best you could do is give your `table-wrapper` a fixed height larger than the table with the header (hard to determine ahead of time, and likely needs JavaScript).

Or, give the table a `max-height` of `100%` and set its `overflow` to `hidden`:

```css
.table-wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: green;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

table {
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

thead {
  visibility: collapse;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-wrapper">
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Head</th>        
    <th>Head</th>
    <th>Head</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>    
    <tr><td>Content</td></tr>        
    <tr><td>Content</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Content</td></tr>        
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

But that kind of defeats the purpose of having `overflow: auto` on the `table-wrapper`… You'll need to pick your poison. Or wait until someone smarter than me answers :).